# how to make a react page as responsvie irrespective of screen size

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, responsive

I am using `React JS` for develop a web page for that I just created a login page with styling. but when I minimize the browser width or checking in mobile alignment is not good. but I am new to making a webpage as responsive.

can anyone please help me how to make responsive web page.

**React JS:**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import "../css/Login.css";
import endpointConfig from '../services/EndpointConfig';
import { useAuthHeader, useSignIn ,useSignOut } from "react-auth-kit";
import LoginService from "../services/LoginService";

export default function Login() {
  const [loginId, setLoginId] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const loginService = new LoginService();
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { setAuth, setHeader } = useAuthHeader();
  const signIn = useSignIn();
  const [loginStatus, setLoginStatus] = useState(null);

  function validateForm() {
    return loginId.length > 0 && password.length > 0;
  }

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
  try{
    event.preventDefault();
    loginService.setLoginId(loginId);
    loginService.setPassword(password);
    const result = await loginService.validateLogin(loginId,password);
    if (result && result.response === "success") {
          window.location.href = "/dashboard";
    } else {
      setLoginStatus("failed");
    }
    }catch(error){
        setLoginStatus("failed");
    }
  }

  return (
    <form
      name="vishing_form"
      method="post"
      className="login_tab_form"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
    >
      <p align="center" style={{ fontWeight: 'bolder', fontSize: '18px', fontFamily: 'helvetica' }}>
        Login
      </p>
      <div className="loginFormInnerDiv">
      <div>
        <label>Login ID</label>
        <input className="loginTextField"
          autoFocus
          type="text"
          value={loginId}
          onChange={(e) => setLoginId(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input className="loginTextField"
          type="password"
          value={password}
          onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
        />
      </div>
          {loginStatus === "failed" && (
            <p style={{ color: "red",fontSize:"1rem", marginTop: "10px", marginLeft: "3rem" }}>
              Invalid credentials. Please try again.
            </p>
          )}
      <div>
        <button
          id="submit"
          type="submit"
          name="login"
          className="submitBtn"
          disabled={!validateForm()}
        >
          Login
        </button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
```

**Login.css**

```
.login-form {
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-top: 140px;
}

.login_tab_form{
    border:4px groove #34495e;
    padding:8px;
    width   : 32%;
    margin-left  : 35%;
    margin-top: 140px;
}

.forgotPwd{
    width       : 70px;
    margin-left : 15%;
    margin-top  : 5px;
    font-family:Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.form {
    border: 6px groove #34495e;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 40%;
}

#submit {
    width: 41%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: rgb(17, 41, 162) !important;
    color: #fff;
    border: none;
    padding: .4rem 2rem;
    margin-left:37%;
    margin-top:5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.forgot-pwd {
    width: 70px;
    margin-left: 15%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
}
label{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align :left;
    width:20%;
    padding:5px;
    margin-left: 7% !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}

::placeholder {

    color: #6c757d;

}
::placeholder {

    color: #6c757d;

}
element {

}
.loginTextField {
    width: 41% !important;
}
.loginFormInnerDiv{
    padding:5% 0% 5% 0%;
}
```

normal size:

[image]

**minimized browser:**

[image]

**mobile view**

[image]

This is how I am getting in different screens please help me how to adjust them independent of screen size.

Thanks

Comment: Making a responsive page is a _huge_ subject, you are better of using tutorials. The only thing we cant know here is if whether you have a viewport meta tag with correct content, and without that, we can't really know if your page will _ever be responsive_.